# CakePHP 3: Routes in Shell

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have Shell to handle different Cronjob tasks. Within such a task, I'd like to generate a link that will be send by email. For this, using `Cake\Routing\Router` should be an option. The code looks like this:

```
namespace App\Shell\Task;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

class ActivitiesSendTask extends Shell
{
  public function main()
  {
    $url = Router::url(['controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'index'], true);
    // ...
```

Calling the task from the terminal always throws a `MissingRouteException` for the `Router::url()` call:

```
Exception: A route matching "array ('controller' => 'Posts', ...)" could not be found.
```

`App.fullBaseUrl` in `bootstap_cli.php` is set correctly as described in  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#routing-in-shells-cli

But it seems the app routes defined in `config/routes.php` are not available in the cli environment. And even a simple route to /:controller/:action is not created.

Any ideas how to solve this problem and make the app routes available in a shell task?

**edit:** the output of `bin/cake routes` shows the following:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route name                     | URI template                      | Defaults                                                                                       |
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| news:home                      | /                                 | {"controller":"News","action":"home","language":"","plugin":null}                              |
| pages:display                  | /pages/*                          | {"controller":"Pages","action":"display","language":"","plugin":null}                          |
| contacts:index                 | /contact/*                        | {"controller":"Contacts","action":"index","language":"","plugin":null}                         |
| search:index                   | /search*                          | {"controller":"Search","action":"index","language":"","plugin":null}                           |
...
| _controller:index              | /:controller                      | {"action":"index","language":"","plugin":null}                                                 |
| _controller:_action            | /:controller/:action/*            | {"action":"index","language":"","plugin":null}                                                 |
```

Comment: For starters it should most probably be `Posts`, not `posts`. That being said, routes should generally be available in the CLI environment. Have you checked for example `Router::routes()` to confirm that there really are no routes loaded?

Comment: Run the `bin/cake routes` command to see what routes are loaded on the CLI. They are definitely loaded. It throws not found because it wasn't found.

Comment: Thanks, both of you are right. The routes are loaded in the CLI. `bin/cake routes` and also `Router::routes()` inside `ActivitiesSendTask::main()` return all the routes. That's seems to be correct. I also updated `posts` to `Posts`. But I still get a MissingRouteException when calling `Router::url(...)`... but why?

Comment: Most likely simply because there is no matching route, but it's hard to tell without knowing what routes are connected - please update your question with the results of `bin/cake routes`.

Comment: @ndm I updated the question with the output of `bin/cake routes`. These are not all the routes, but at least one of the `_controller: ...` routes should match. In a normal controller, a `Route::url()` call with the same parameter results in the correct url without exception.

Comment: From your routes dump it seems that you are defining a `language` key in the defaults, which is missing in your `Router::url()` call, hence things don't match.

Comment: @ndm Perfect! Thanks for pointing me to the language parameter, this was the problem. Setting this key worked without exception. This took me to a bug in one of my `Router::addUrlFilter()` where the language parameter should be handled automatically if no value is given. Bug fixed - check. Merry Christmas!